# how to select a opened image with DLGCreateImagePopup in created dialog

Tags: image, input, dialog, dm-script

I creat a dialog with DLGCreateImagePopup to select a opened image. But after I select the image, I cannot do anything for that image. How to get the image ID or name of the selected image?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it as a posed dialog (i.e. get the image after clicking the OK button), you could do it as follows:

```
Class CMyDLG : UIframe
{
       TagGroup DLG,DLGItems,imgPop        
       object Init(object self)
       {
              DLG = DLGCreateDialog("Test",DLGItems)
              imgPop = DLGCreateImagePopup()
              DLGItems.DLGAddElement( imgPop )       
              return self.super.init(DLG)
       }

       image GetSelectedImage( object self )
       {
              string selectedImageLabel
              imgPop.DLGGetValue(selectedImageLabel)
              Result("\n" + selectedImageLabel)
              // From the string, get the label
              string label = selectedImageLabel.left( selectedImageLabel.find(":") )
              Result("\n" + label)
              // From label, return image
              return FindImageByLabel(label)
       }
}

// main
{
       object dlg = Alloc(CMyDLG).Init()
       dlg.Pose()
       image selected := dlg.GetSelectedImage()
       if ( selected.ImageIsValid() )
              selected.SetName( "Selected" + random())
       else Throw( "Error, nothing selected." )
}
```

If you want to do something with the image while the dialog is still displayed (modeless dialog) you'd have to attach a OnChanged-type method to the item as in:

```
Class CMyDLG : UIframe
{
       TagGroup DLG,DLGItems,imgPop        
        void FieldChanged(object self, taggroup tg)
        {
              string selectedImageLabel
               tg.DLGGetValue(selectedImageLabel)
              Result("\n" + selectedImageLabel)
              // From the string, get the label
              string label = selectedImageLabel.left( selectedImageLabel.find(":") )
              Result("\n" + label)
              // From label, return image
              image selected := FindImageByLabel(label)
              if ( selected.ImageIsValid() )
                  selected.SetName( "Selected" + random())
              else Throw( "Error, nothing selected." )
       }

        object Init(object self)
       {
              DLG = DLGCreateDialog("Test",DLGItems)
              imgPop = DLGCreateImagePopup().DLGChangedMethod("FieldChanged")
              DLGItems.DLGAddElement( imgPop )       
              return self.super.init(DLG)
       }

}

// main
{
    Alloc(CMyDLG).Init().display("myDialog")   
}
```

---

Note, that when I've tested this script on the latest GMS 3, I've noticed a *bug*. The Changed-method (and hence the actual selection) seems to happen only when the drop-down is accessed *a second time*.