# A problem for selecting a image from the imagepupop dialog

Tags: dialog, dm-script

One more question. If I create a image-popup dialog, I find it only works when the frontimage (the top one in the image list). If other image is selected, the program will report "the image used in the expression does not exist". I can not understand the logic behind this error.

The following is a modified code pasted in the answer of the previous question. It can work well if the first image is selected, but the error message appears if the second image is selected.

I use GSM 2.30.xxxx

```
Class CMyDLG : UIframe
{
   TagGroup DLG,DLGItems,imgPop        
   object Init(object self)
   {
          DLG = DLGCreateDialog("Test",DLGItems)
          imgPop = DLGCreateImagePopup()
          DLGItems.DLGAddElement( imgPop )       
          return self.super.init(DLG)
   }
   image GetSelectedImage( object self )
   {
          string selectedImageLabel
          imgPop.DLGGetValue(selectedImageLabel) //DLGGetValue can return the label of the image diretly
          Result("\n" + selectedImageLabel)
          // From the string, get the label
          //string label = selectedImageLabel.left( selectedImageLabel.find(":") )              
          //Result("\n" + label)
          // From label, return image
          //return FindImageByLabel(label)
          return FindImageByLabel(selectedImageLabel)
   }
}

// main
{       
   object dlg = Alloc(CMyDLG).Init()
   dlg.Pose()
   image selected = dlg.GetSelectedImage()
   if ( selected.ImageIsValid() )
   {
          selected.SetName( "Selected" + random())
          selected.ShowImage()
    }
   else Throw( "Error, nothing selected." )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the test code on GMS 3.3 it works *except* for the bug mentioned. I presume it's the same for GMS 2.3 but I haven't verified.

To make sure we test the same thing, here are exact instructions and a break-down:

---

- Start out with two images **A** and **B** and **A** being front-most.
- Run script
- Don't change anything in the dialog
- Press OK
- **ERROR**

The dialog - taggroup does not (yet) hold any value. It possibly should, I consider this a *bug*.

---

- Start out with two images **A** and **B** and **A** being front-most.
- Run script
- Click the selection box and select "A" from the drop-down
- Press OK
- **A is correctly selected**

---

- Start out with two images **A** and **B** and **A** being front-most.
- Run script
- Click the selection box and select "B" from the drop-down
- Press OK
- **ERROR**

The dialog - taggroup does not (yet) hold any value. It definitly should, I consider this a *bug*. It is most likely what you were describing?

---

- Start out with two images **A** and **B** and **A** being front-most.
- Run script
- Click the selection box and select "A" from the drop-down
- Click the selection box and select "B" from the drop-down
- Press OK
- **B is correctly selected**

> ### To summarize:
>
> Yes, there is a bug and nothing wrong with your script.
>
> The selection box only works after selecting an items ***for the second time***.

Comment: If you click B first and click B again, still error. It seem that you should click A first and then click which image you want to ensure the correct response. So this dialog losts its value.

Comment: @YuanYao I agree. It's a bug to be fixed. One can, however, create one's own "image-selector" UI item using (and populating) your own dropdown menu control.

Answer (score 0):

The example code (first script) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58171237/1302888) seems to work on any of the open images when selected.

However, there is the (mentioned) bug that it does not work on first selection, only when you select one image and then another.

If your code fails, please provided a slimmed-down code-example of the failing code so that a mistake can possibly be spotted.

Comment: I appended the code to the question, with little chang. Thank you very much.